# Replacing one by one when searching in Vim

Tags: vim

I am currently search vim using `/Paul`

If I had a sentence like this:

```
Paul likes to play with Paul
```

Now when I type:

```
/Paul
```

The two pauls on the line are highlighted in yellow.
The first `n` takes me to the first Paul and the second `n` takes me to the last Paul.

How could I replace the Paul that is currently next (or in view)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. How about cw?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do it again:

```
Let's start. Paul likes to play with Paul
-
```

<kbd>/</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
Let's start. Paul likes to play with Paul
             -
```

<kbd>n</kbd>

```
Let's start. Paul likes to play with Paul
                                     -
```

<kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

```
Let's start. Paul likes to play with Andrew
                                          -
```

Is it what you want to do?

Comment: Yes it would be nice though not to get into insert mode after changing the word

Comment: You can add `<Esc>` or `<Ctrl>]` after the replacement to go back in normal mode. The other solution is to record a macro. Press `qq` to start recording then `ciwAndrew<Esc>q`. To can go to the next work with `n` and execute the macro with `@q`

Answer (score 7):

Use a substitution with the `c` flag for confirm.

```
:%s/Paul/Ringo/gc
```

Or you can just do the search like you are and use the `gn` motion along with `.` to accomplish this.

- `cgnRingo<esc>`
- `.` to repeat. You can also use `n` to go to the next location or skip one.

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h gn
:h .
```